# Sentiment analysis using LSTM on imbalanced citation dataset

Tags: nlp, pytorch, lstm, sentiment-analysis

I have an extremely unbalanced dataset for sentiment classification. https://cl.awaisathar.com/citation-sentiment-corpus/

- Class POSITIVE:829
- Class NEGATIVE:280
- Class NEUTRAL: 7627

Here is my network:

```
Sentiment_LSTM(
  (embedding): Embedding(5491, 400)
  (lstm): LSTM(400, 512, num_layers=2, batch_first=True, dropout=0.5)
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=3, bias=True)
  (sig): Sigmoid()
)
```

Loss function:

```py
lr=0.001

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(net.parameters(), lr=lr)
```

My accuracy is low on the small classes. How can i improve it futher?

Comment: Can you write a few words about the dataset? What do you mean by small classes?

Comment: @Jindřich 
Class POSITIVE:829 
Class NEGATIVE:280 
Class NEUTRAL: 7627.
Here is the class distribution. Now when I test my network on test dataset. Most of the accuracy is dominated by Neutral class. The small classes(pos and neg) are not so accurate.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using a **softmax** instead of **three sigmoids**. With sigmoids, you model three conditionally independent distributions. This not really what you want because the review and can be either positive, neutral, or negative, but not, for instance, positive and neutral at the same time — they not independent at all. With a softmax, the probability distribution will get spread in the three classes and the model might better understand that being positive means at the same time not being neutral.

Note also that with softmax, you need to use [`NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) or [`CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss) instead of `BCELoss`.

If this is not enough, you can add weighting to the loss, so the positive and negative reviews are more prominent in the training. For that, you need to do the loss reduction yourself. Set `reduction='none'`, so you won't get a single number, but a vector of loss values, one for each example in the batch. Then you can multiply this with a weight vector (I would start with something as setting the weight of 0.5 for neutral and 1 for the other two). Then, you can average the loss just by calling the `mean` method on the tensor.

Comment: I replaced it with following network structure.

Sentiment_LSTM(  
  (embedding): Embedding(19612, 400)  
  (lstm): LSTM(400, 512, num_layers=2, batch_first=True, dropout=0.5)  
  (dropout): Dropout(p=0.5, inplace=False)  
  (fc): Linear(in_features=512, out_features=3, bias=True)  
)